# Dont send message with inlinekeyboard pyrogram

Tags: python, pyrogram

I try to send InlineKeyboard but catch error *TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string*
CODE:

```
    async def send_afisha_to_channel(self,about: dict) -> None:
        async with self.app:
            await self.app.send_photo(
                chat_id='@filmas_tiktok',
                photo=about['img_link'],
                caption=MessagePaterns.FILM_AFISH_PATTERN(about),
                parse_mode='html',
                reply_markup=KeyBoards.get_link_kb_pyro(about['shorturl'])
                )
```

Class KeyBoards

```
class KeyBoards:
    @staticmethod
    def get_link_kb_pyro(url: str, text: str = 'Смотреть') -> pyrokbmk:
        btn = pyrokbbut(text,url=url)
        kb = pyrokbmk(inline_keyboard=[btn])
        return kb
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kirill\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Kirill\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Kirill\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Kirill\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Kirill\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:\Users\Kirill\PycharmProjects\test\main.py", line 41, in admin_commands
    await pyroClient.send_afisha_to_channel(about=about)
  File "c:\Users\Kirill\PycharmProjects\test\contrib\utils.py", line 35, in send_afisha_to_channel
    await self.app.send_photo(
  File "C:\Users\Kirill\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\messages\send_photo.py", line 180, in send_photo
    reply_markup=await reply_markup.write(self) if reply_markup else None,
  File "C:\Users\Kirill\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\types\bots_and_keyboards\inline_keyboard_markup.py", line 62, in write
    for b in r:
  File "C:\Users\Kirill\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\types\object.py", line 94, in __getitem__
    return getattr(self, item)
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

A keyboard button include url to site and text of button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this part right:

```py
btn = pyrokbbut(text,url=url)
kb = pyrokbmk(inline_keyboard=[btn])
```

you're defining one button, and pass that as a list to the keyboard itself. Pyrogram and its InlineKeyboardMarkup require a list of lists, where the outer list is the rows, the inner list the buttons of each row.

You'll want something that looks like this:

```py
keyboard = [  # List of rows:
    [button, button],  # First Row
    [button],  # Second Row
]
```

Comment: Thanks you! Inattentively read the documentation.